# Send heavy files (> 1go) with Dart/Flutter web throw HTTP with multipart to Furioos API

Tags: flutter, dart, http, multipart

i'm looking to send a heavy .zip file ( > 1go ) using a post http request to the [Furioos API](https://api.furioos.com/v1/api-docs/#/) using multipart on flutter web. If i try to create a multipart file with this file, my web flutter app crash because the task is too long. I'm not sure to really understand how to send this type of file. Should i chunk the bytes of the files myself ? This is automatic with mutlipart ? I'm not a experimented dev on the http side. the Furioos API is really not educative to explain me how to do this. So if guys can guide me a little with this, i thanks you.

```
final stream = await _createChuncks(file.bytes!);
    http.MultipartFile multipartFile = http.MultipartFile(
      'file',
      stream,
      file.size,
      filename: file.name,
      contentType: MediaType('application', 'zip'),
    );
    http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest( 'POST', uri )
      ..files.add(multipartFile)
    final response = await request.send();
```

I get this issue RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed when my file is more than 500 mb

Comment: https://apipheny.io/what-is-post-request/. I want to send use the /applicationbinaries/{applicationBinaryID}/upload from Furioos API